# If next date from current date php foreach

Tags: php, loops, date, foreach

so I'm trying to show only the closest next concert for an bunch of concert. A "playing next at" if you will.

This is basically what i want to do;

```
if (date is closest to now and in the future ) {
"echo 'active';"
break;
}
```

This is what i got so far:

```
<?php $tour = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tourplaces', true);

foreach( $tour as $tour ) {

$now = date('d M Y H:i');
$date_unformated = $tour['tour_when'];
$date_unformated = str_replace('/', '-', $date_unformated);
$date =  date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($date_unformated));


if ($date > $now) {
echo 'active';
} 
?>
```

But i only want the closest one in the future to show. Not all of the future dates to show.

Comment: Why are you starting and ending PHP tags like that? You never switch out of PHP so you only need the 1st and last tags

Comment: Its wordpress so it is a bunch of html inbetween.

Comment: Ah okay. Well you are setting the `$now` variable on every loop too, which shouldn't cause an "issue" really but it is needless. You should declare `$now` at the same time as your `$tour` variable. Also, pretty sure your `foreach` has a syntax error, you can't have the output variable the same as the input variable. I would rename `$tour` to `$tours` (As I am assuming there are multiple) and switch your foreach to `foreach($tours as $tour)` as this makes sense naming-wise. Each loop is a single tour out of the array of tours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I made it work! :-D

Final code:

```
<?php $tours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tourplaces', true); 
$min_tour = null;
$min_date = null;
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
$now = date('YmdHi');
 ?>
<?php foreach( $tours as $tour ) { ?>
<?php
$date_unformated = $tour['tour_when'];
$date_unformated = str_replace('/', '-', $date_unformated);
//$date =  date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($date_unformated)); 
$date =  date('YmdHi', strtotime($date_unformated)); ?>
<?php
if($date > $now && ($min_date == null || $date < $min_date)) {
    $min_date = $date;
    $min_tour = $tour;
        } }
 ?>
<?php  foreach( $tours as $tour ) { if ($tour == $min_tour) { ?>
    <div class="tourplace active">
        <address><?php echo $min_tour['tour_location']; ?> </address><br/>
<?php
$date_unformated = $min_tour['tour_when'];
$date_unformated = str_replace('/', '-', $date_unformated);
$date =  date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($date_unformated)); 
 ?>
    <time><?php echo $date; ?></time><br/>
<?php if ($min_tour['tour_book']) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $min_tour['tour_book']; ?>" target="_blank" class="link btn">Book ticket</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>


    <? } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this is what i got out of it so far:

```
<?php $tours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tourplaces', true); 
    if( count($tour) <= 0) { echo "No tours in the future"; }
$min_tour = null;
$min_date = null;
$now = date('d M Y H:i');
 ?>
<?php foreach( $tours as $tour ) { ?>
<?php
$date_unformated = $tour['tour_when'];
$date_unformated = str_replace('/', '-', $date_unformated);
$date =  date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($date_unformated)); ?>
<div class="tourplace <?php if ($date > $now) {
if($min_date == null || $date < $min_date) {
    $min_date = $date;
    $min_tour = $tour;
    echo 'active';
        }
 }?>">
```

But unfortunately it didn't work. It does show the future dates though. Did I miss something?

Answer (score -1):

What you want is to get the nearest date in the future, so the minimal date which still lies in the future. So you have to find the minimum. Here is a bit code. I did not test it, but it should make clear what I wanted to say.

```
<?php 
// renamed $tour to $tours, because it was confusing with the foreach loop
$tours = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tourplaces', true); 
// in case $tours is an empty array, we echo an info
if( count($tour) <= 0) echo "No tours in the future";
// we want to remember what our closes future tour was
// init to null, as there may be no tour in the future
$min_tour = null;
$min_date = null;
// as  GrumpyCrouton said, $now should be define once outside the loop
$now = date('d M Y H:i');
foreach( $tours as $tour ) {
    $date_unformated = $tour['tour_when'];
    $date_unformated = str_replace('/', '-', $date_unformated);
    $date =  date('d M Y H:i', strtotime($date_unformated));
    if ($date > $now) {
        // check if the current date is before the last found minimal date
        // also check for null in case we havent found a miminmal date yet
        if($min_date == null || $date < $min_date) {
             // our current tour is closer to now and is in the future
             // so save the current tour as minimal
             $min_date = $date;
             $min_tour = $tour;
        }
    }
}
// you have to check for $min_tour == null, in case the was no tour in the future
echo "closest tour:" . $min_tour;
```

Comment: Changing OPs variable names with no explanation on why or even mentioning you did it :/ Also not actually explaining any of your code at all really is not helpful to OP trying to learn or to future readers trying to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the explanation sufficed. I added some comments to explain what I wanted to achieve in the code.

Comment: Don't now if you see my answer when I dont add a comment (new to stackoverflow)... But I answered anyhow.

Comment: I can't comment on you answer, so I write here. After the code of your answer, the $tour you want is in $min_tour. You don't do anything with it though. (like "echo $tour['some_text'];") Also if you echo "active" in the if-case, it always echos whenever it find a closer future date; it does not necessarily echo only once for the closest fure date.

Comment: Oh, I see! so how do I get the if (...) { echo 'active'; } to work? I tried if ($min_tour) { echo 'active'; } but got active for every one of them.

Comment: In your Answer's last line you close the foreach-loop. After that the simplest way would be: foreach($tours as $tour) { if($tour == $min_tour) { echo "active"; } else { echo "inactive"; } }. If I understood you right, that you want to echo 'active' for the closest tour in the future. (If you just need the closest tour in the future you could accres $min_tour after the foreach-loop).

Comment: That means you have to move "<div class="tourplace", ">" to after the foreach-loop. foreach($tours as $tour) { ... } #this is should be your last lines -> "<div class=tourplace <?php foreach($tours as $tour) { if ($tour == $min_tour) { echo "active"; } } ?> > "

Answer (score -2):

You can use break; to end the foreach. In case your array is correctly sorted by date.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

```
 foreach( $tour as $tour ) {

   // your code

    if ($date > $now) {
        echo 'active';
        break;
    }

  }
```

For comparison change the date format to:

```
$date = date ("YmdHi");
```

Also for your tour date.
You will get a date which can be compared in an if statement.